# 640px PSD file need to fix in all device

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, viewport

> i have only one PSD file which has width 640px from client and i have to fix in all device, from ios to windows with different screen device.
>
> my problem is that i don't want to crop different images for small and big size device. I searched for some solution but i am confused with all using viewport, mediaquery. and new iphone5 have 1136px resolution i don't know how to achive with this PSD. I want to crop one size image for all device is it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after looking for solution for a long time i found that u can use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640">
```

let browser do other work for you. this i found from apple.com. just view source http://www.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can 'crop' using css, unless there is a sort "hacky" way of doing it.

But using mediaqueries you can most certainly resize it to fit your browsers very easily:

```
<script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/largeres.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1236px)" > 

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mediumres.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 720px)">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/smallres.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 360px)">
</script>
```

smallres.css

```
yourImage{
    height: 60%;
    width: 60%;
```

}

mediumres.css

```
yourImage{
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
```

}

largeres.css

```
yourImage{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
```

}

Comment: Actually, I think Cropping is kind of possible using the clear property in CSS

Comment: Yeah, I looked in to it, I came across some css3 elements.  I guess it's entirely dependant on how compatible the cropping needs to be.  Probably not the best choice to do it that way currently.  It's not even supported on ie9 or lower correctly.

Comment: I dream of the day when IE will finally catch up with other browsers in terms of supporting things . . .

Comment: Actually this example seems to work for me in IE8+  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_clip

Answer (score 0):

You could set it as a background image and use `background-size: cover` to stretch it for you, for more information [see here](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/), and a demo [here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php) (try resizing your browser window to see it in action).

Unfortunately because this is a CSS3 property IE8 and below don't support it, you can overcome this using filters (the first link has more information on that) or you go for an all together more complicated solution involving JavaScript.

Media queries are also a possible solution, but I'm afraid I don't know much about them, you make a good point about new smartphones having screens that are (technically) over 1000px wide.

I'm sure there'd be a way around that using media queries, possibly with handheld instead of media? I'm not entirely sure but if you want to explore that more I'm sure Google will be your friend.

Comment: i am just looking for solution for mobile device. i know we can achieve with viewport:scale, mediaquery but i am confused with both which one to use and in what way